# On the success of Ajax-Jquery how can I Replace or Append the cell values of table after the submission of Modal form in ASP.NET MVC5 C#

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

The data is updated to my database table when the modal form is submitted and closes successfully but what I need is without a page refresh data should be updated in cells of the table.

I am new to JQuery, If someone resolve this matter to me I would really appreciate it.

Here It is the Script which I have placed at the end of my partial view:

```
function btndbsave(obj) {
    var ele = $(obj);
    var id = ele.attr("data-model-id");
    var itemlist = [];
    var name = $("[name = 'NameTxtID']").val();
    var phone = $("[name = 'PhoneTxtID']").val();
    var email = $("[name ='EmailTxtID']").val();
    var AjaxVM = { Id: id, Name: name, Phone: phone, Email: email };
    itemlist.push(AjaxVM);


    console.log(itemlist)
    debugger;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/Edit', //
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({ AjaxVM }),
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function () {
            alert("success");
            $('#newmodal').modal('hide');
            $('#tbDetails>tbody>td').find("tr").html(AjaxVM);

            //$('#tbDetails').find("tbody>tr").append(itemlist);
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
};
```

Partial View As a Modal:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title">Edit Record</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name, "NameTxt", "NameTxtID", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control col-md-6", @name = "Name[]" } })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Phone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Phone, "PhoneTxt", "PhoneTxtID", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control col-md-6", @name = "Phone[]" } })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Email, "EmailTxt", "EmailTxtID", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control col-md-6", @name = "Email[]" } })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnSave" data-model-id="@Model.Id" onclick="btndbsave(this)" value="Save changes">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

Here it the table of View :

```
 <table id="tbDetails" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Id</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Phone</td>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td>Options</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td width="100" class="idField">@item.Id</td>
                    <td>@item.Name</td>
                    <td>@item.Phone</td>
                    <td>@item.Email</td>
                    <td>
                        <a class="delete" data-model-id="@item.Id" onclick="Delete(this)"><img src="/UserImages/delete.png" /></a>
                        <a class="edit-record" data-model-id="@item.Id" onclick="Edit(this)" ><img src="/UserImages/pencil.png" /></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Here it is the Controller:

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult Edit(Models.AjaxVM ajaxVM)
{
    using (var db = new PracticeEntities())
    {
        var checkforid = db.AjaxTable.Where(x => x.Id == ajaxVM.Id).FirstOrDefault();
        if (checkforid != null)
        {
            checkforid.Name = ajaxVM.Name;
            checkforid.Email = ajaxVM.Email;
            checkforid.Phone = ajaxVM.Phone;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("error", "Record has not been Updated");
        }

        return Json(ajaxVM);
    }

}
```

Edit method in a Seperate JS file :

```
function Edit(obj) {
debugger;
var ele = $(obj);
var url = "/Home/Edit"; // the url to the controller
var id = ele.attr('data-model-id'); // the id that's given to each button in the list
$.get(url + '/' + id, function (data) {
    $('#newmodal').find(".modal-content").html(data);
    $('#newmodal').modal('show');
});
};
```

Comment: What is the html of the `<tr>` that you want to update? (and not a lot is making sense in your code - there is no point returning back what you just sent, your `EditorFor()` code is incorrect, and `ModelState.AddModelError` makes no sense because you are not returning a view, and creating the `itemlist` in the script makes no sense)

Comment: Wait let Me edit the View of this code @StephenMuecke

Comment: @StephenMuecke Actually I forgot to add view of table.

Comment: So what you are doing is clicking the `<a class="edit-record" ..>` to open the model, and editing that data, then saving it? And if its successfully saved, you now want to update the `<td>` elements in that row?

Comment: You are passing an object to the html code. AjaxVM is an object. Not an html content.

Comment: Ya @StephenMuecke exactly I want to update the content of <td> elements without a page refresh. Right now the data is updated to my database and the <td> elements are updated on a page refresh.

Comment: Give me 10 min or so and I will add answer and correct all the other issues you have

Comment: Sure take your time @StephenMuecke

Comment: There is an important part of your code that is missing in the question, which is the `Edit` script (can you please edit  that in)

Comment: I have edited now please check it @StephenMuecke

Comment: OK, that should be changed as well - its pointless to waste time and resources making an ajax call to get the data that already exists in the `<tr>` element - you should just include the modal in the view initially based on a default `AjaxVM` instance - e.g. by using `@Html.Partial("yourPartialView", new AjaxVM())` or by using `@Html.Action(...)`

Comment: Please if you update the code it will really help me to understand what are you trying to say

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181480/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-ibrahim-inam).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your use of `EditorFor()` makes no sense, and the usage should be just

```
 @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name, "new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control col-md-6" } })
```

Next you script to save the data should be

```
function btndbsave(obj) {
    var ele = $(obj);
    var id = ele.attr("data-model-id");
    var name = $("#Name]").val();
    var phone = $("#Phone").val();
    var email = $("#Email").val();
    var AjaxVM = { Id: id, Name: name, Phone: phone, Email: email };

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Edit", "Home")', // don't hard code your url's
        dataType: "json",
        data: AjaxVM,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (response) {
            .... // see notes below
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
};
```

Note however that you modal should include a `<form>` and the `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` code to give you client side validation along with a submit button so that your script becomes

```
$('form').submit(function(e) { // or give the form an id attribute and use that
    e.preventDefault();
    ... // make ajax call
});
```

Next, you controller method need only return a value indicating success or otherwise (along with any error message if applicable), for example

```
return Json(new { success = true }); // if saved
return Json(new { success = false, message = "...." }); if not saved
```

Note that adding a `ModelStateError` makes no sense because you are not returning a view

and then in the ajax call back, you update the `<td>` elements is successful (or display error if not). In order to do that, include a global javascript variable to store the current row

and change the link that opens the modal to

```
<a class="edit-record" data-model-id="@item.Id" href="#" ><img src="/UserImages/pencil.png" /></a>
```

and the script to

```
var currentrow;
$('.edit-record').click(function() {
    currentrow = $(this).closest('tr'); // assign the current row
    ... // load and display the modal
});

$.ajax({
    ....
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.success) {
            // Update the current row
            var cells = currentrow.find('td');
            cells.eq(1).text(name);
            cells.eq(2).text(phone);
            cells.eq(3).text(email);
        } else {
            ... // oops - display the message in response.message?
        }
    }
....
}
```

Note also that there is no need to make an ajax call to load the modal because you already have all the data in the view. Instead, include the html for editing a `AjaxVM` in the initial view, for example, using

```
@Html.Partial(""_Edit", new AjaxVM())
```

then update the values of the inputs when you display the modal

```
$('.edit-record').click(function() {
    currentrow = $(this).closest('tr');
    var cells = currentrow.find('td');
    $('#Name').val(cells.eq(1).text());
    $('#Phone').val(cells.eq(2).text());   
    $('#Email').val(cells.eq(3).text()); 
    $('#newmodal').modal('show');
});
```